# Bash script for running parallel commands using input from a file

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell

I am trying to make a shell script which reads a configuration file and executes commands for each line in parallel.

For example, I have IPs.cfg, which can contain a variable amount of IPs. It could be one or several

IPs.cfg

```
145.x.x.x
176.x.x.x
192.x.x.x
```

I want to read the file and then execute a command for each line at the same time... for instance :

```
scp test.iso root@$IP1:/tmp &
scp test.iso root@$IP2:/tmp &
scp test.iso root@$IP3:/tmp &
wait
```

The way I'm thinking this is that I store the IPs into an array

```
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a array < IPs.cfg
```

Then I extract the number of lines from the file and decrease it by 1 since the array starts at 0.

```
NUMLINES=`cat IPs.cfg | wc -l`
NUMLINES=$((NUMLINES-1))
```

Now I want to execute the commands all at the same time. It's a variable number of parameters so I can't just manually use `scp test.iso root@${array[0]}:/tmp & scp test.iso root@${array[1]}:/tmp & so on`. I could use a while loop, but that would mean doing the commands one at a time. I'm also thinking about using recursion, but I have never done that in a bash script.

It might be a silly question, but what are my options here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop should look like this:

```
while read -r ip ; do
   scp test.iso "root@$ip:/tmp" &
done < IPs.conf
wait
```

Comment: I just tested this out. It works flawlessly. I did not even know that you can use `&` like that. Thank you very much for the quick answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of [GNU parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html)

Answer (score 0):

with this trick, you can control the number of simultaneous processes running at the same:

```
cat IPs.conf | xargs -n1 -I{} -P10 scp test.iso "root@{}:/tmp"
```

Check the `-p10` which means to use 10 processes at the same time.